# Equation/formula/algorithm for figuring out binary polynomial equation from integer

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

Say you have this sequence of examples:

```
2^0 = 1
2^1 = 2
2^1 + 2^0 = 3
2^2 = 4
2^2 + 2^0 = 5
2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 6
2^3 - 2^0 = 7
2^3 = 8
...
```

There is some equation in there for going from the output integer like $6$ to the *shortest* input equation like $2^2 + 2^1$, *where the base digit is always 2*. So these seem like [polynomial equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_code) where $ax$ is always 2. I am wondering how to figure out automatically what equation any integer will turn into.

Comment: The "shortest solution" also happens to be unique. Have a search on "decimal to binary conversion". Edit: I just saw you're allowing subtraction. How would you decide between $2^3-2^1$ and $2^2+2^1$?

Comment: Somehow it would have to decide, maybe with some heuristics. Doesn't matter as long as it's somehow possible. It could just pick one.

Comment: There is a mistake in your examples: $2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 \not = 6$. It should be $2^2 + 2^1 = 6$ I think.

Comment: Are you asking for pseudocode or are you asking for a formula? If so, what format would this formula output with?